# How to change the order of key-value pairs in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to move the last key-value pair to the first place?

```py
d = {1 : 'a', 2 : 'b', 3 : 'c'}
```

Here is what I'm trying to get

```py
d = {3 : 'c', 1 : 'a', 2 : 'b'}
```

I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: Why do you want it? The beauty of dicts is that the order does not matter...

Comment: Unless you use an `OrderedDict`, which only preserves the insertion order, there is no implicit order to dictionary entries in Python. If you care about that, use a list instead.

Comment: @TheDude In fact there is. Since 3.7 , insertion order of the dict is guaranteed to be preserved.

Comment: @Kaiyakha: We often want this for json dumps, since json package prints key-value pairs in dicts based on their order, which is usually (but not necessarily ideally) insertion order.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be:

```py
d = {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"}
print(dict([d.popitem()]) | d)
```

output

```
{3: 'c', 1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
```

`popitem()` gives a tuple of the last key-value pair in the dictionary. We put it into a list to create an iterable of pair items, then we can call `dict()` on it.

[from documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> ...Otherwise, the positional argument must be an iterable object. Each
> item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two
> objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new
> dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value.

This works on version 3.9 and above. Since version 3.7, insertion order of the dict is guaranteed to be preserved. Since version 3.9 , dictionaries support union `|` operator.

Comment: `{**dict([d.popitem()]), **d}` for python <3.9

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny right. Also in-place `.update()` method would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

It works only if your Python version maintains insertion order (Python 3.7 and later), but you can try:

```py
d = {1 : 'a', 2 : 'b', 3 : 'c'}
# last key
last_k = next(reversed(d))
# put the last key-value pair before the rest
d = {last_k: d.pop(last_k), **d}
d
# {3: 'c', 1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a systematic approach, when the `dict` is "big", you can a mapper which contains a list of old key-new key and then use a dict-comprehension to get a dictionary with the new ordering.

```
d = {1 : 'a', 2 : 'b', 3 : 'c'}

mapper = [(1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2)]

new_d = {k_new: d[k_new] for _, k_new in mapper}
```